# GeoTools Omitting Quotes in its Queries?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geotools

I have a table in my PostgreSQL 8.4 with a column 'Shape' of type 'geometry'.  When I start up Tomcat my GeoServer throws an exception:

```
24 Sep 16:20:25 WARN [geotools.jdbc] - Error occured determing srid for my_table.Shape
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "shape" does not exist
```

In my PostgreSQL log I can see the corresponding query and error:

```
ERROR:  column "shape" does not exist at character 77
STATEMENT:  SELECT ST_SRID("Shape") FROM "core"."my_table" WHERE Shape IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
```

Just to explore, I tried that same query from psql, and it failed in the same way. I tried it again, except I put double quotes around the 'Shape' in the WHERE clause:

```
gtda=# SELECT ST_SRID("Shape") FROM "core"."my_table" WHERE "Shape" IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1;
 st_srid
---------
    4326
(1 row)
```

What is generating that query, why is it omitting the quotes, and is there something I can do about it? I have a number of similar tables, all of which are popping this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a pull request against the GeoTools data store in question, or open a bug report against GeoTool/GeoServer on jira.codehaus.org (get a login at xircles.codehaus.org)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I see that http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOT-4541 already captures it.